# Printing the number of times the word appears from a txt file

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to find the number of times the word "the" appears in a txt file. With the code below, I keep getting the 0 as my output when it should be 4520. I'm using the delimiter to separate "the", but it doesn't seem to count it at all. The delimiter worked when I counted all words using `"[^a-zA-Z]+"`.

```
in.useDelimiter("[^the]+");
while (in.hasNext()) {
    String words = in.next();
    words = words.toLowerCase();
    wordCount++;
}
System.out.println("The total number of 'the' is " + theWord);
```

Comment: This happens because you never increment `theWord`. Instead, you increment a different variable `wordCount`

Comment: `[^the]` means "not any of the letters `t`, `h`, or `e`, means means that if input is `"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"`, the result is tokens `"he"`, `"e"`, and `"the"`. Not what you want!

Comment: Oh sorry, that was left from a previous code I tried. It still doesn't work nonetheless

Comment: @DissolvedMan - Use `()` instead of `[]`. The square bracket checks for individual characters not the text as a whole. Check my answer for a demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\\b(?i)(the)\\b` as the regex where `\\b` stands for the word boundary, `i` stands for case insensitive and `(the)` is for `the` as a whole. Note that `[]` checks for individual characters enclosed by it, not for the enclosed text as a whole.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = null;
        try {
            in = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"));
            int wordCount = 0, len;
            while (in.hasNextLine()) {
                len = in.nextLine().split("\\b(?i)(the)\\b").length;
                wordCount = len == 0 ? wordCount + 1 : wordCount + len - 1;
            }
            in.close();
            System.out.println("The total number of 'the' is " + wordCount);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File does not exist");
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
The total number of 'the' is 5
```

**Content of file.txt:**

```
The cat jumped over the rat.
The is written as THE in capital letter.
He gave them the sword.
```

Comment: This is tested code. So, definitely there is some other problem. Is your file at the correct location? I mean can you check `if (new File("file.txt").exists()) System.out.println("File exists"); else System.out.println("File does not exist");`

Comment: The file is in the correct location. I still tried what you said, and no luck.

Comment: You mean, you are getting the output: `File exists`?

Comment: Yes, the file exists.

Comment: I can't believe it. I just tested my code again and it worked perfectly. I've also just updated my code to include the message if the file is not found. Can you simply copy my code and run it without any change?

Comment: Ok. Your code works. However, it doesn't give the right number, but I'll try to go off of that.

Comment: `However, it doesn't give the right number` - this is not correct. I can bet £10 if you can prove it :). I have tested my code so many times and with different content and every time, it gave me the correct number.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210408/discussion-between-dissolvedman-and-arvind-kumar-avinash).

Comment: *FYI:* `(?i)(the)` can be combined to `(?i:the)`

Comment: ***This code doesn't work:*** Input `"It's the first of the year"` gives result **3**, but there are only 2 `the` words. Input `"the"` gives result **0**, but there is 1 `the` word. You simply cannot use `Scanner` and `useDelimiter()` like that to count the words. The entire premise of using `useDelimiter()` to count the delimiters is flawed. It probably could be done, but would be *very* convoluted.

Comment: Oh, and negative points too for not closing the `Scanner` wrapping a file stream.

Comment: Fixed it. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

In Java 9+, you can count the number of times a word occurs in a text file as follows:

```
static long countWord(String filename, String word) throws IOException {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b" + Pattern.quote(word) + "\\b", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    return Files.lines(Paths.get(filename)).flatMap(s -> p.matcher(s).results()).count();
}
```

*Test*

```
System.out.println(countWord("test.txt", "the"));
```

*test.txt*

```
The quick brown fox
jumps over the lazy dog
```

*Output*

```
2
```

Java 8 version:

```
static int countWord(String filename, String word) throws IOException {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b" + Pattern.quote(word) + "\\b", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    return Files.lines(Paths.get(filename)).mapToInt(s -> {
        int count = 0;
        for (Matcher m = p.matcher(s); m.find(); )
            count++;
        return count;
    }).sum();
}
```

Java 7 version:

```
static int countWord(String filename, String word) throws IOException {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b" + Pattern.quote(word) + "\\b", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    int count = 0;
    try (BufferedReader in = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(filename), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
        for (String line; (line = in.readLine()) != null; )
            for (Matcher m = p.matcher(line); m.find(); )
                count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

Full code for a Java 7+ version, without use of a method, and using the much slower `Scanner`, since OP seems to have trouble copy/pasting the methods above into their code.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int count = 0;
        try (Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("test.txt"))) {
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\bthe\\b", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
            while (in.hasNextLine())
                for (Matcher m = p.matcher(in.nextLine()); m.find(); )
                    count++;
        }
        System.out.println("The total number of 'the' is " + count);
    }
}
```

For comparison, the full version using the first method in this answer would be:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("The total number of 'the' is " + countWord("test.txt", "the"));
    }
    static long countWord(String filename, String word) throws IOException {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b" + Pattern.quote(word) + "\\b", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        return Files.lines(Paths.get(filename)).flatMap(s -> p.matcher(s).results()).count();
    }
}
```

Comment: I keep trying to use the Java 7 version, but I keep getting syntax errors within the parameters in countWord

Comment: @DissolvedMan I copy/pasted the code from question into an empty class, and added imports. No syntax errors. Don't know what you're doing wrong. --- Did you perhaps paste the code into a method, e.g. your `main` method? You can't have methods inside methods.

Comment: I'm using Eclipse, I don't think it matters. When I copy the code it tells me to remove static, then has 3 syntax errors. (1) The first "(", ; expected. (2)  the comma after filename "," ; expected. (3) String word insert ";" to complete LocalVariableDeclarationStatement